# How do I crop and resize images using C# back-end for my android application?

Tags: c#, android, image-processing, c#-4.0, transformation

I am developing an android application which requires users to upload few images and then crop and resize them to fit in design of a web application. I don't want to perform these operations on user device to avoid slugginess in application. Please recommend some server side API or library.

Comment: I recommend to do some research. Did a search for you to start with: [results](http://www.csharp-tutorial.info/2016/01/image-processing-libraries-csharp.html) P.s. if you look at Related links on the right, you will find answers to questions: How to crop/resize image in c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to take a look at [**Amend Library**](https://github.com/amendcloud/amend_android) for Android(Java) and [**Amend Library**](https://github.com/amendcloud/amend_dotnet) for Android(C#) on GitHub. It is an awesome and on the fly image processing Solution.I have used it in multiple applications.It is very light weighted and support many image processing features through just **one API call**. Documentation is available at [Amend Website](http://amendcloud.com/). Also you can install the **Amend** package through Nuget from [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Amend/).

Comment: Then can you please vote the question so that others can find it useful.